# How to Create a React Component in Isolation?

Tags: reactjs

I need to create a popup message component which gets user feedback. Is there any way for me to develop a component like this (some type of dialog/modal probably) without making a new page to test it on?

Like, is there any way for me to develop this individual popup message, or other small components, in isolation, and then later attach them to a larger page component?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you could use an online editor like [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io)
Or you could use a dedicated create react app for testing / developing a component alone

Comment: That might work, but then I think the new component wouldn't have access to the props, themes, etc. from the original App to make it work. Is there any sort of way to make some sort of test window within the App?

Comment: you could use an existing app and render it there sure and remove / comment out everything that was inside to render it alone

Answer (score 0):

You can just make the popup component, and add it into your App.js to see if it works as far as working on local workspace goes. you can also try some sort of virtual code editor like codepen, stackblitz, codesandbox, etc, then copy the code over into your workspace.